# How to read Windows Security events possibly with JNA?

Tags: java, windows, jna

I am reading Windows event logs with JNA as below:

```
EventLogIterator iterator = new EventLogIterator("Security");
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    EventLogRecord curRecord = iterator.next();
}
```

But an exception is thrown (other channels like Application are read successfully):

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: A required privilege is not held by the client.
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util$EventLogIterator.<init>(Advapi32Util.java:1929)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util$EventLogIterator.<init>(Advapi32Util.java:1922)
    at com.emc.windowsagent.EventLogReader.getEventsByIterator(EventLogReader.java:155)
    at com.emc.windowsagent.WindowsAgentMain.main(WindowsAgentMain.java:17)
```

Is there a way to obtain privilege to read Security events?

Comment: Depending on the scope: run it with an admin user?

Comment: I haven't yet tried that one. Nevertheless I wanted every user to access Security events.

Comment: Is that than not more of a windows security concern than a java one, even if it's JNI?

Answer (score 0):

Run the application as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there Follow simple steps
To get the security logs from the windows we need to change the security permisions via regedit`.

Steps to follow

1. Type `regedit` in windows+run
2. Find
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system`
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system`
3. In the right pane of System key, find EnableLUA DWORD and double click on it.

Then restart the operating system.And then add the java code

it will work.